# React setState multiple arrays based on index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, input

I have a rather tricky question to ask,
I'm working on a page that accepts several inputs from the Data-Base
and with that I'm generating several inputs( the number of inputs  is not constant)

basically like this:

```
 const form = this.state.inputs.map((input, i) => {
      if (input) {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor={input.inputLabel}>{input.inputName}</label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-input">
              <input
                name={`${input.inputName}-${i}`}
                type={input.inputType}
                id={input.inputLabel}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
```

after generating the form with the unknown number of values ( depends on the Data-Base)
I want to save all the values of that form, but because I do not know the number of inputs I made 2 arrays ( I need to save the value and the name to be later shown in a different page)

```
  state = {
  ....
    inputData: {
      names: [],
      values: []
    }
  ....
  };
```

but I'm having trouble of actually saving the values in the setState

```
 onChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    var nameIndex = name.split('-');
    const names = [];
    const values = [];
    values[nameIndex[1]] = value;
    names[nameIndex[1]] = nameIndex[0];
    const inputData = { names, values };
    this.setState({ inputData });
  };
```

the setState works like this:
on my map I give each input a name that contains the index that's generated by the map so the name is like "inputname-1", and I use split to take out the 1 and update the two arrays I did in the setState (values,names) and everytime the user writes in the input it changes the value inside the array like so: values[1]=(users input...) ,
but I noticed that if I change the 2nd value for example, the values before him in the index 1 and 0 become undefined, am I missing something?

Comment: instead of `const names = [];
    const values = [];` do `const names = this.state.inputData.names;
    const values = this.state.inputData.values`

Comment: but that means I will be changing the state directly , am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think so. just change `const` to `var` it would be better

Comment: @evgeni fotia, I think it does, and const var doesn't change anything, I'm not changing the binding of the value, just the context. EDIT: I'm 100% sure it's wrong, if you assign a=[1,2,3] and b=a and b[1]=9, it will change the a array, so what you suggested is directly changing the state and its wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `names` and `values` array with just one index populated in it. This is why you are overwriting other indices in the array

You could do something like this if you want to update only the specific indexes without mutation:

```
const { name, value } = e.target;
const [key, index] = name.split('-');

this.setState(prevState => ({
   ...prevState,
   inputData: {
      values: Object.assign([], {...prevState.inputData.values }, { [index]: value }),
      names: Object.assign([], {...prevState.inputData.names }, { [index]: key })
   }
}))
```

Another option is to take a copy of the `prevState.inputData.values` using the spread syntax and update it's value at specific index and then set it to `inputData`:

```
const { name, value } = e.target;
const [key, index] = name.split('-');

this.setState(prevState => {
  const cloneValues = [...prevState.inputData.values],
        cloneNames = [...prevState.inputData.names];

  cloneValues[index] = value;
  cloneNames[index] = key;

  return {
    ...prevState,
    inputData: {
      values: cloneValues,
      names: cloneNames
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how that part works, "[index]: value" , could you explain to me please?

Comment: @AlexK does either my solution work? I'll add an explanation for `Object.assign`

Comment: the first solution does not compile, and quite frankly I don't understand it, I do know how object assign works.

Comment: @AlexK sorry about that. Forgot to add some brackets `{}`. Updated now. I think second solution is much more straight forward and should work

Comment: oh now it makes more sense, the 2nd option is easier I agree, but the first works as well, you basically make 2 objects with each index as the key? and you combine them to the empty array?

Comment: @AlexK you got it. Spreading an array within a flower brackets `{...array }` creates an object with indexes as keys and each value as value. Then you merge this object with another object which your index to be updated as key. This repaces the key in the spread object. Object.assign is usually used to merge objects. But, when used with `Object.assing([], someObject)`, the keys of that object become the indices in the array.

Comment: may I bother you one last time? I'm just trying to recreate that and the syntax does not work like so: a=object.assign([],{[4]:1,[5]:2,[6]:3},{[4]:5}) do you know whats wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188226/discussion-between-alex-k-and-adiga).